# How can I make a filtered lookup view that doesn't remove the value in it as I delete items from the lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I have a list of Projects. As they are completed I want to delete the item (or tag it as completed). The Project Library looks up "Project Name" from the list of Projects (so that it is easy to find in the drop down). But if I delete the Project from the list it removes that metadata from the Project Library item.

I can't use third party solutions or Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this requires an couple of extra fields:

- `Status` to store the current status of the project
- `Lookup Project Name` which is the target for lookup
- `Project Name` the ordinary lookup field
- `Display Project Name` an additional field in the lookup to display the real `Project Name`

Here is the setup instructions

1. In the Projects list create a choice field `Status` where one of the values is `closed`
2. In the Projects list create a calculated field `Lookup Project Name` with a formular like `IF([Status]="closed","",[Project Name])` (Where `[Project Name]` is the field with the project name)
3. In the Project Library list create the lookup column using the calculated field `[Lookup Project Name]`, but with [Project Name] as an additional field
4. In views of Project Library list don't use the lookup column, but instead the `[Lookup:Project Name]` column

This will create a column in projects which is blank for items you don't want to be able to select and happily enough SharePoint won't show blank items. The reason for including Project Name as an additional field and using that in views is that otherwise your views will show blank values when the corresponding project is closed.